# How to implement Recursive Paginated Network Call using RxSwift

Tags: swift, pagination, rx-swift, reactive

I have an endpoint that returns the items of the current page. Also, if you want to get next page's items, you have to construct a URL with the next page's hash. This hash returns as property in the response of the previous request. As you understand, we need a recursive network call.

When a request finishes, a new request will begin until hash returns null through the response.

Then, I need to bind all collected data into an array.

How can I build something like that in RxSwift? I would appreciate if you describe that concept.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Asking us to describe building something results in a tutorial because it's such a broad question.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this: https://gist.github.com/danielt1263/ec1032375498eb95aa260239b289d263

```
/**
 Calls `producer` with `seed` then emits result and also passes it to `pred`. Will continue to call `producer` with new values as long as `pred` returns values.
 - parameter seed: The starting value needed for the first producer call.
 - parameter pred: This closure determines what the next value pass into producer should be or returns nil if no more calls are necessary.
 - parameter producer: The function that produces the Single result.
 - returns: An observable that emits each producer's value.
 */
func emitWhile<T, U>(seed: U, pred: @escaping (T) -> U?, producer: @escaping (U) -> Single<T>) -> Observable<T>
```

The `seed` is the hash for the first page. The `pred` takes the result of a network request, extracts the hash for the next page and returns it (or returns nil if there is no next page.) The `producer` takes the hash and returns an observable that will make the request for the page when it is subscribed to.

You will likely want to collect all the elements using either scan or reduce to emit all of the pages as a single array.